# Pause application running without using MsgBox

Tags: c#, vb.net

When internet connection is off my application opens a MsgBox and tells to user "Please provide internet connection then click Retry button"

I want to do same thing but without using MsgBox.

Is there any other control which is integrated Windows Form?

Comment: use another Form with a label control and (possibly) an "OK" button only

Comment: How can you pause for user input without some sort of modal ("stop application running") dialog and button?

Comment: Thanks but I need a control which is integrated main Windows Form.

Comment: Add a button to main Windows Form and do nothing until they click it

Comment: What do you mean "stop application running"?  Technically a program  never stops until it exits.  I think you mean "stop responding to user events" in which case you just need to disable whatever form is currently being displayed (`Form.Enabled = false`).

Comment: When msgbox opens application pause, when Retry button click application continue running. So, I need another method instead of using msgbox.

Comment: [**`Form.ShowDialog()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know little to none of c#, but I know in VB.NET there's an option like

> Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

I use this all the time to freeze applications. I know c# is similar to VB.NET so look into it! :)